# Bit size changing using Verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to write a 32 bit reg to 22 bit reg while conserving the number and its sign.

```
reg [31:0] test_dat0; //test_dat0 <= -4 (binaire)
reg [22:0] test_dat1;
test_dat1 <= test_dat0 ; ??? //what is the value of test_dat1 here
```

is it right ? 
thank you

Comment: 1/ Provide some code formatting. 2/ I am not sure what you want to do. You can not pack a 32 bit number into 22 bits unless you know not the whole 32 bit range is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number is between -2097152 and 2097151, then just truncate the 10 MSBs (`test_dat1 <= test_dat0[21:0]`).

Otherwise you cannot fit a 32bit number into a 22bit register whilst maintaining the value. It would be equivalent to trying to fit 2-litres of soda into a 1-litre bottle without losing any.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that's exactly what i did , and yes i know that the number does not surpass 22 bit, the problem is i'm not sure whether the sign of the number sties or not, i have 2 32 bit buses in my design and when reading data i only need 22bit and there are some values i send that are negative, can that be a problem ?

Comment: @user8254046 for numbers \$-2^{21}\$ to \$2^{21}-1\$, expressed as 32bit numbers, the 11 MSBs will always be either all 1's for negative numbers, or all 0's for positive numbers. So you can truncate them at will.

Comment: @user8254046 to go the other way (from small to large) with signed numbers, you perform sign extension which involves copying the MSB into all new bits. e.g. `test_dat0 <= {{(10){test_dat1[21]}},test_dat1}`